# htaccess rewrite links and duplicate it

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have this htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^einfogarden.com$
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.einfogarden.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+single\.php\?title=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/? [R=302,L,NE]

## Adding a trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=302]

# convert %20 to -
RewriteRule "^(\S*) +(\S* .*)$" $1-$2 [L,NE]
RewriteRule "^(\S*) (\S*)$" $1-$2 [L,R=302,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ single.php?title=$1 [NE,L,QSA]
```

which should remove single.php?title= from url and replace the 20% by slash and it work corrctly.
but i have 2 problem  1. it stop the css in my website 2. if you try to click any link (except) the home page it will give you something like this http://www.einfogarden.com/%D9%81%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%AF-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%B1%D8%AC%D9%8A%D8%B1/single.php?title=%D9%81%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%AF%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%86%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A7%D8%A6%D8%B9%D8%A9
it duplicate the link

Comment: i solve the css problem

Comment: Don't add '/' at the end of your url. yourweb.com/home and not yourweb.com/home/

Answer (score 0):

You are asking in the .htaccess the url of your current page. 
`So yourwebsite.com/home` will be `yourwebsite.com/home/home`
I edited your code a little. using this will do fine.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)$ $1 [L] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/cache
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css|jpg|gif|zip|js)

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/?$ index.php?page1=$1&page2=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?page1=$1 [L] 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ http://www.google.com/ [R]
```

This is a easy way the use SEO url's
The `RewriteRule` is for creating a new var to your url.